# Submit patch in gerrit without parents

Tags: git, patch, gerrit

I'm currently setting up a gerrit server in my new company. I used to use gerrit for few years now but I never setup one.

I installed gerrit 2.13.5 and I'm trying to configure it. I have two last issues I'm trying to fix (I'll only discuss one here).

I have a list of commits A->B->C

A is the parent of B, B is the parent of C

- Someone reject (-2) my patch A and B (because they're bad) but accept C (+2).
- C is completly unrelated to A and B (another file in another folder into my project)

A button "Submit including parents" appears to my commit C but I cannot cherry-pick it into gerrit/master branch since A and B are reject.

Since C is not related to A or B, but I don't want to have to much local branches, I've done all 3 commits into the same branch.

I use cherry-pick submit option into gerrit configuration

```
[submit]
action = cherry pick
mergeContent = true
```

I supposed that using this option, I could cherry-pick any commits with no direct parents dependencies. I used to do so in my previous company but I cannot succeed to setup gerrit this way here.

If anyone have ideas or questions I will really by please to get or answer it.

Cheers.

Comment: If C is not related to A and B, then base it on the upstream branch rather than on B. This way it won't have A and B as parents and you will have no problems merging it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've a very little different version of Gerrit (2.13.6) and I've tried to reproduce the issue here. I've found the following:

1. If the project strategy is "Cherry Pick", the button shows "Submit"

[image]

2. If the project strategy is any other option, the button shows "Submit including parents"

[image]

Using the first option it was possible to submit the second commit before the first one without issues.

So, I think is a good idea to check if you really have the strategy "Cherry Pick" set for your specific project. If the "Cherry Pick" strategy is correctly set then you could try to update for the last available version (2.13.7).

Comment: Once again you are right. I change the strategy from "Rebase if Necessary" to "Cherry Pick" after creating some projects. The new created projects have the right strategy the older ones have not. I change all wrong projects strategy one by one and everything is right now. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

There is one more possibility irrespective of your project startegy in this case.

- Click `Rebase` button.
- Check the option `Change parent revision`
- Input the git's sha-id of any un-submitted change on the branch you may want to rebase on or the `HEAD` commit of the branch.

This will create a new patch set for the change. Reviews will have to be done again and also verifies will execute again. Although this is not a direct submission, this can help if you do not have gerrit server setup rights.